# How to add an extra field in Django model form only when the object exists?

Tags: django, django-forms

Lets say I have a model form like this:

```
class PersonForm(forms.ModelForm):
    full_name = forms.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = '__all__'
```

The `full_name` field is not a database field. I want to have the field `full_name` appear only if the object exists, ie, not on add, and the set the initial value to `instance.first_name + ' ' + instance.last_name`. On add, because the `first_name` and `last_name` don't exist yet, the field `full_name` is simply not shown. How can I do this? Moreover, will this extra field affect my save process?

Edit: I am trying to do this admin, therefore, no answers mentioning views or templates.

Comment: What do you want to do with the data in this field?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Just display the data. A read-only field would be a better idea, however, I am using a custom widget that only works on non-disabled inputs.

Answer (score 0):

In your html template file you can check for an ID of the form instance, like this

```
{% if form.instance.place_id %}
    {# we are editing the object #}
{% endif%}
```

place_id has to be replaced by an id of the object or some other field.